# Is it correct to say "Oh, I have missed the stop" when I forgot to get off the bus at a correct bus stop?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

We often say "Oh, I have missed the bus" when the bus had left before I arrived at the bus stop.

Now, I was on the bus and busy talking with a friend and forgot to get off the bus at a correct bus stop.

Is it correct to say "**Oh, I have missed the stop**" the same way we say "**Oh, I have missed the bus**"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that works, but it is a little clearer to say “I missed **my** stop” because that makes it explicit that you are talking about the stop you intended to take.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct. However, it's slightly  more natural to use the pronoun "my" instead of "the". There also doesn't seem to be a reason to use the past perfect, so I would also prefer the simple past.

See for example this [anecdote on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/BritishSuccess/comments/57xdhy/i_accidentally_missed_my_bus_stop_due_to/):

> I accidentally **missed my bus stop** due to daydreaming... when I went up the front of the bus the driver just laughed, did a slight detour, and dropped me right at the door of the train station rather than on the main road where I would have been originally.
> It was almost worth the initial shame of admitting I **missed my stop**.